# css position of datepicker: absolute gives right position for button but incorrect on press

Tags: css

I am a css beginner so apologies in advance if I am asking basic questions.

I am using a jquery datepicker in my web application and have an issue with the positioning of the jquery date button. I am using a css framework (yaml) which has a whole set of defined styles for buttons so what I have needed to do is override all the pre-defineed styles.

When I specify the following styles...

```
button.ui-datepicker-trigger, button.ui-datepicker-trigger:hover {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background-image:none !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    display: inline !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: 0 0.5em !important;
}
```

The date button is slightly too high and not in line with the input field...

[image]

When I fix this and specify the following styles...

```
button.ui-datepicker-trigger, button.ui-datepicker-trigger:hover {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    background-image:none !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    display: inline !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important; 
    box-shadow: none !important;
    padding: 0 0.5em !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;   
}
```

The date button is in line with the next field which is what I want.

[image]

BUT after changing the style of the button to use absolute (3 end lines of 2nd css extract above), whilst i am doing a mousepress the date control jumps up about 15 pixeles up the screen.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I might fix this? And a good explanation as to what is happening for my understanding.

thanks

Comment: jsfiddle? or give url

Comment: Is there an `:active` style getting in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try another solution by using the calendar icon inside the textbox.

Check this here :- http://jsfiddle.net/33Xxk/

```
.tInput_datepick {
width: 250px;
color: #555555;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-left: 7px;
background-image: url(http://www.bay.k12.fl.us/portals/18/Images/calendar_icon.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
background-position-y: -5px;
height: 25px !important;
border: 1px solid #888e9c !important;
background-color: #f4f5f9 !important;
cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: thank your for this suggestion. I am very happy with the results. I am not a ui specialist but am looking to move into that field. Sometimes you just don't think about little things like this. Thanks again

Comment: To use this css what changes should be done in jQuery UI datePicker javascript to avoid duplicate icons? @Anup